# Change Passenger Port using Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, passenger

I try using [capistrano-rails](https://github.com/capistrano/rails) gem for deployment of my application in production. Unfortunately the standard port for passenger is 3000, which I cannot use.

How does I need to change my `deploy.rb` file so that I can start the passenger with a different port after deployment?

Thanks for your support!

The following doesn't change anything:

```
set :passenger_restart_with_touch, true
set :passenger_port, 10666

set :passenger_roles, :app
set :passenger_restart_runner, :sequence
set :passenger_restart_wait, 5
set :passenger_restart_limit, 2
set :passenger_restart_with_sudo, false
set :passenger_environment_variables, {}
set :passenger_restart_command, 'passenger-config restart-app'
set :passenger_restart_options, -> { "#{deploy_to} --ignore-app-not-running" }

namespace :deploy do

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Passenger documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/standalone/deploy/ruby/#step-1-create-a-passenger-config-file) it is possible to create `Passengerfile.json` in Rails root directory with value for port:

```
{
  "port": 10666,
}
```

Comment: it works, just needed to update my passenger to the latest version..had an older (4.0.58) passenger version running before and there it seems this was not yet used.